# Ionic IOS app NSURLConnection error 1100

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, nsurlconnection

I am trying to run my ionic app as a ios native app and am getting a strange URL connection error that is preventing the data from being populated on my app's view.  When I run the App in the web browser as an iphone it runs and populates fine, but when running it on the native ios it doesn't populate the page as expected using the API data.  I have checked the console and the API is in fact being called, but the xcode console is printing out the following for the 2 API calls which populate the page's data:

```
2018-02-19 11:30:21.199933-0500 MyApp[1429:350591] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2018-02-19 11:30:21.202556-0500 MyApp[1429:350591] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
```

I have looked and seen that code -1100 is typically a file not found type of issue, but I am unsure of how this would be happening, as it is just an API call being made to return the data, which is then being stored in an ionic card format.

Comment: did you manage to solve this problem 
i am running into it now

Comment: I upgraded Cordova, this fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below steps:

```
1) Delete node modules,plugins folder
2) ionic cordova platform remove ios
3) npm install
4) ionic cordova platform add ios
5) ionic cordova build ios
```