# NSURLConnection error 1100 while running ionic app on iOS

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I have build an app with ionic 4 and cordova. On android the app runs like a charm but on iOS I just get some strange problems... like others do ([Ionic IOS app NSURLConnection error 1100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870411/ionic-ios-app-nsurlconnection-error-1100), [ionic 4 app shows white screen on ios with error code 1100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55931112/ionic-4-app-shows-white-screen-on-ios-with-error-code-1100)).
The app ionic build runs fine without any errors and just a few warnings of unused imports. Also the xcode build is fast and successfull. But when the app is running on a real device or simulator, I just get a blank white screen. In the console I get this with addional debugging:

I found like mentioned some similar issues and also added the environment variable (`CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS = 1`) for advanced network logging to get more infos in the console (whole file: https://pastebin.com/yecJ5Vzy) or some snippets here:

```
2019-05-03 10:59:49.788736+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312031] CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:1] 10:59:49.787 {
DiskCookieStorage Construction: Binary{ Disk Cookies: { /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/23CCB045-0976-4DD0-A19B-0BD8CB6825FD/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies, <0 cookies in 0 domains> clean not writing } }
                     Accessing: <CFURL 0x282db3c60 [0x1bda5d610]>{string = file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/13371337-0976-4DD0-A19B-0BD8CXYZAS/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies, encoding = 13371337, base = (null)}
                          Path: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/13371337-0976-4DD0-A19B-0BD8CXYZAS/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
                Read from disk: <0 cookies in 0 domains>
                         Dirty: NO
                       Writing: NO
                        Policy: 0
} [1:1]
2019-05-03 10:59:49.788845+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312031] CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:2] 10:59:49.788 {
DiskCookieStorage Journaling On: Binary{ Disk Cookies: { /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/13371337-0976-4DD0-A19B-0BD8CXYZAS/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies, <0 cookies in 0 domains> clean not writing } }
                           File: <CFURL 0x282db3c60 [0x1bda5d610]>{string = file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/13371337-0976-4DD0-A19B-0BD8CXYZAS/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies, encoding = 13371337, base = (null)}
} [1:2]
2019-05-03 10:59:49.879254+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312031] Apache Cordova native platform version 5.0.0 is starting.
2019-05-03 10:59:49.879772+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312031] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2019-05-03 10:59:49.901704+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312031] Using UIWebView
2019-05-03 10:59:49.904145+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312031] [CDVTimer][console] 0.041008ms
2019-05-03 10:59:49.904228+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312031] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.049949ms
2019-05-03 10:59:49.905236+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312031] Unlimited access to network resources
2019-05-03 10:59:49.905271+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312031] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 1.001954ms
2019-05-03 10:59:49.905338+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312031] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.050068ms
2019-05-03 10:59:49.905379+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312031] [CDVTimer][backgroundfetch] 0.025034ms
2019-05-03 10:59:49.905397+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312031] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 1.327991ms
2019-05-03 10:59:50.139954+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312031] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2019-05-03 10:59:50.158278+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312115] CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:3] 10:59:50.158 {
LoaderWhatToDo: (null)
       Request: <CFURL 0x282db7c00 [0x1bda5d610]>{string = file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/13371337-0976-4DD0-A19B-0BD8CXYZAS/MyNiceApp.app/www/index.html, encoding = 13371337, base = (null)}
   CachePolicy: 0
      WhatToDo: originload
   CreateToNow: 0.00069s
} [1:3]
2019-05-03 10:59:50.161705+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312031] Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
2019-05-03 10:59:50.162212+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312031] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2019-05-03 10:59:50.162894+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312115] CFNetwork Diagnostics [1:4] 10:59:50.162 {
LoaderWhatToDo: (null)
       Request: <CFURL 0x282d94060 [0x1bda5d610]>{string = file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/13371337-0976-4DD0-A19B-0BD8CXYZAS/MyNiceApp.app/www/index.html, encoding = 13371337, base = (null)}
   CachePolicy: 0
      WhatToDo: originload
   CreateToNow: 0.00030s
} [1:4]
```

And a bit later in the console log:

```
2019-05-03 10:59:50.278000+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312114] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2019-05-03 10:59:50.278024+0200 MyNiceApp[3426:1312114] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
```

It seems like the app can't load its own files.. since the error -1100 means `NSURLErrorFileDoesNotExist`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the same issue and after quite a bit struggle and R&D this is what worked for me.

Seems like relative path is taken by IOS so in your src -> index.html please change this
base href="/"
to
base href="./" (note dot at the beginning of the /)

this will load all the relevant js files (cordova.js, polyfill.js etc.)

the 1100 errors are files not being found due to absolute path.

Comment: This worked for me, it fixed the issue, however it brought some weird behaviour such as images not being found and app name for plugins with permissions

Comment: Icons and images are not loaded correctly :/ @JoseGeorges did you found a solution?

Comment: @JanMoritz I rebuilt the app with Flutter

Answer (score 1):

After researching a lot a trying a lot of stuff, my solution was to execute this command:

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview --save`

Comment: This one here does solve the issue as well, however for people using location services it will break those for them. from experience